# Does damage reduction from Shadowfell Brand Tattoo stack with resistance?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, damage-resistance, damage-reduction

[Shadowfell Brand Tattoo](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/shadowfell-brand-tattoo), the new magic item from [Tasha's](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe) has this effect:

> **Shadowy Defense**. When you take damage, you can use your reaction to become insubstantial for
> a moment, *halving the damage you take*. Then the reaction can't be used again until the next sunset.

**Does this reduction stack with reduction from having resistance?**

Comment: Related: [Do Rage and Uncanny Dodge stack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79864/33707)

Answer (score 10):

#### They stack.

The rules for resistance say:

> Multiple instances of resistance or vulnerability that affect the same damage type count as only one instance. For example, if a creature has resistance to fire damage as well as resistance to all nonmagical damage, the damage of a nonmagical fire is reduced by half against the creature, not reduced by three-quarters.

But *Shadowy Defense doesn't grant resistance at all*, so there is no reason it cannot be used in conjunction with another feature that grants resistance. It should also be noted that resistance is applied *after* Shadowy Defense:

> Resistance and then vulnerability are applied after all other modifiers to damage.

#### The "same name" stacking rule is a red herring.

Citing the "features with different names stack" rule is something of a red herring: *two features with different names that both grant resistance would not stack because resistance never stacks, no matter the source.* Shadowy Defense stacks with resistance because it is not resistance, not because it has a different name than some other feature.

Answer (score 6):

## Damage *reduction* is not damage *resistance* so they stack.

[Only game effects with the same **name** don't stack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/running-the-game#CombiningGameEffects):

> [W]hen two or more game features have **the same name**, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap.